# VB Net Graphics DrawString construct Fail

Tags: vb.net, printing, graphics

I have NO idea what is wrong with my construct in the Second Graphics.DrawString line of code
My Question is Why is the construction of that line of code FAILING and the line above it does Not Fail
This is the FAILING line of code

```
 e.Graphics.DrawString(strTo, 12, Brushes.Red, 45, 50)


    Private Sub pdDoc_PrintPage(sender As Object, e As Printing.PrintPageEventArgs) Handles pdDoc.PrintPage
    Dim fontSize As Integer = 30
    Dim labelFont As Font = New Font("Times New Roman", fontSize, FontStyle.Bold)

    Dim strTo As String = "Kitchen"
    Dim lblArray(2) As String
    lblArray(0) = "Kitchen"

    e.Graphics.DrawString(lblArray(0), labelFont, Brushes.Black, 500, 950)
    e.Graphics.DrawString(strTo, 12, Brushes.Red, 45, 50)
```

**After reading the two answers and Here is my updated FIX for the error's in the line of code above**

```
    Dim labelFont As Font = New Font("Times New Roman", fontSize, FontStyle.Bold)
    Dim strTo As Object = "Kitchen"
    e.Graphics.DrawString(strTo.ToString, labelFont, Brushes.Red, 300, 300)
```

Comment: For future reference, please always accurately define "failing", "an error", "it's not working" or similar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first `DrawString` is OK, but the second one is incorrect.

```
public void DrawString (string s, System.Drawing.Font font, System.Drawing.Brush brush, float x, float y, System.Drawing.StringFormat format);
```

@CaiusJard has already identified the error, so I am clarifying more.

Here it accepts a Font object, not Integer. By 12 I think you have confused with size. First you can declare a font object with:

```
Dim myFont As Font = New Font("FONT NAME",12)
```

Then you can use `myFont` instead of 12.

Comment: I have a time of it calling SUB's constructed and have developed a bad habit of avoiding them I now realize that the two errors were with strTo and 12 YES I was thing size and not using the creation code to define the object Font I will post my FIX in the question Thanks for the Explanation

Answer (score 3):

I've taken the liberty of aligning your commas between the working and not:

```
e.Graphics.DrawString(lblArray(0), labelFont, Brushes.Black, 500, 950)
e.Graphics.DrawString(strTo      , 12       , Brushes.Red  , 45 , 50 )
                                   ^^^^^^^^^
```

What kind of `Font` is `12` ?

Comment: OK it was late and I was trying everything labelFont was a bad naming convention it was from another project were I was printing labels As pointed out the term FAIL was not descriptive of where or how the code was broken In this case at two places the strTo and the 12 I will Post my FIX to the QUESTION thanks